# Saving of Settings of NIK plugins (like Color Efex Pro) per photo

Tags: dng, tiff

I use Color Efex Pro of NIK a lot. Sometimes just to try out a setting and to know how it looks without feeling the need to save all those huge TIFF files. 
There is a possibility to save settings but it is rather awkward and it is more thought for like 'generic' settings.

I would like to save settings on a per image basis. Preferably the same name as the raw/dng file so that I can recreate the tiff again. It seems something very simple. Does anybody has any idea why this is not implemented. (I first ask here before going to the NIK software group. Just to get some support  or to get explained that this is not such a great idea).

I don't like to have a DNG and a TIFF (or sometimes more then 1) of the same image. If I update some meta-data I have to check everything again. This is another argument not to use TIFF's and DNG's. The only reason for TIFF's I see is for printing (and storing them on the site where they are for sale).

I don't use photoshop. Only Lightroom and NIK plugins.

Answer (score 1):

You can save that. I mean not in a way like it stays tightly related with the photo - but what you can do is after adjusting the settings, you can save all of them in one "Recipe" and later pull that "Recipe" from their "All Recipe" tab.

I am using Color Efex Pro version 4 in Mac and I have this feature available in it.

Comment: Hi Hasin,thanks for pointing out that there is a save option. But really, what I want is support for a save-on-image base in a bit a more convenient way.